# Where is crash point? I am getting below report in firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, imageview

i am getting below crash in **Firebase**. I am not that getting how can i track it or fix it.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

0  CoreFoundation                 0x181c668c8 CFAutorelease.cold.1 + 16

1  CoreFoundation                 0x181b8f06c _CFNonObjCRelease + 42

2  UIKitCore                      0x18612f8ac -[UIImageView _setImageViewContentsForCIImageBackedImage:] + 800

3  UIKitCore                      0x186124df4 -[UIImageView _setImageViewContents:] + 556

4  UIKitCore                      0x186126a1c -[UIImageView _updateState] + 616

5  UIKitCore                      0x18616a16c +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 96

6  UIKitCore                      0x18612e5a4 -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] + 556

7  UIKitCore                      0x186127b10 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 452
```

**With below code**

```
var imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: SuperiY, width: 300, height: 145)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
if let image = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromDiskCache(forKey: URL(string:dictStoreDetail.object(forKey: "image_path") as! String)?.absoluteString) {
      imageView.image  = image
} else {
      imageView.sd_setImage(with:URL(string:dictStoreDetail.object(forKey: "image_path") as! String),placeholderImage:nil,options:.progressiveDownload)
}
imageView.tag = 2500
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: Int((ViewSuper.frame.size.width - 350)/2), y: SuperiY, width: 350, height: 175)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: What does the value for key `image_path` contain? If it’s really a file **path** then the API `URL(string:)` is wrong.

Comment: @vadian its like https://app.xyz.com/uploads/store_logo/1253538271580484616.png
how it should be than ?

Comment: And Its not crashing each time, only some time

Comment: `URL(string:)` requires a string representing a full URL including a scheme like `https://`. Just `app.xyz.com` is not sufficient.

Comment: @vadian its with https:// but when i posted stack overflow removed it automatically.

Comment: I have the similar issue and the problem is in `imageView.image  = image`. In my case `CIImage` is converted to `UIImage`